# onmouseenter\onmouseleave not firing in IE

Tags: javascript

I've tested this function in chrome and firefox and the value is updated properly when the mouse moves in and out of the browser but IE doesn't fire either and the compatibility chart indicates that IE has implemented it it in full since version 5.5.  Does anyone have any ideas?

var mouseisout = false;

document.onmouseleave = function () { mouseisout = true; }

document.onmouseenter = function () { mouseisout = false; }

Comment: Have you checked whether it works on an actual HTML element, instead of document?

Comment: No only on the window and document objects.  I need to know when the browser closes and the mouse is not on the document.

Comment: Well then I'd try it on the html element (document.documentElement) ...

Comment: detecting the the user is trying to close the browser is basically impossible.

Comment: That did it, thanks.  I'll have to do some reading on documentElement.